# Oracle Change Username

Tags: oracle

I use turkish character in my username "İ", its works fine while logging on oracle enterprise with browser but when I try to connect database with visual studio it makes problem so I think 3 diffrent kind of idea may able to help solve this issue.

-How can I change my oracle username ?

-How can I make vs with working turkish characters too("Ç, Ş, İ)"

-How can I create new user without lost any data in oracle manager( İts like create an alias to referance old user's info. tables roles privileges everything must be same, just user name different )

Thank you who feel try to help

Answer (score 1):

Well,

1. you cannot change schema name referring to [Tom Kyte's answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:30020192108317) but you can export the data and then import it to another user
2. *with working turkish characters too ("Ç, Ş, İ)"* - I am not sure if there is a good reason to put national characters to the variable/schema names. Isn't it enough to use English? English was never the language of my country (and I've changed already 2) and it was always enough!
3. according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865586/oracle-how-to-grant-to-a-user-the-rights-to-another-users-objects) you can create a script to grant everything to a new user and then according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706260/oracle-read-only-access-to-the-schema-for-another-user/21706881#21706881) you can easily change schema every time e.g. on login

Comment: 1 okey
2 bro yes you right I regret to use. but its done so I couldnt change pass tense :). now I never user turkish again. But I have to deal with this issue. Thanks.
3)I am gooing to check this.