# oracle schema - to be shared within same DB

Tags: oracle

Recently i imported a db which has multiple users , i have loads of compilation errors in packages because they want to access tables of other users , now i want someone to help me in making all the tables/procedures ... in differecnt users accessible to all users , 
Please not all the users have been made as DBA

What could be the command to make all users data public ?

Primarily there are 3 users who want accessibility within themselves

Please note that i am using oracle 10 G

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to grant privileges to all users's object, right?

This answer should help you: [Grant Select on all Tables Owned By Specific User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187886/grant-select-on-all-tables-owned-by-specific-user) (answer covers only tables, but you can extend it to views, procedures, synonyms, functions, packages, ...)

Comment: BEGIN FOR R IN (SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner='TheOwner') LOOP EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant select on '||R.owner||'.'||R.table_name||' to TheUser'; END LOOP; END;         WHAT IS R ?

Comment: just a variable, an alias for the query

Comment: cannot reference ooverflow table of an index organised table is the error which i am getting :(

Comment: @abhinav you can filter on `IOT_NAME` to get over that. i.e. change the cursor to `SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner='TheOwner' and IOT_NAME is null`