# Want to grant select to a specific user on all tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I use the below to grant select permission to amy on table1:

```
grant select schema.table1 to amy;
```

However, the below does not work:

```
grant select on schema.* to amy;
```

the error is

> ORA-00903: invalid table name

Please advise what is wrong in my command. What I want is grant select to amy on ALL tables.

thanks

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/189496/8843451

Answer (score 1):

[The syntax for the GRANT command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73341782/want-to-grant-select-to-a-specific-user-on-all-tables) (as of Oracle 21c) makes it clear that the granted item can only be a specific object:

**on_object_clause:**

[image: on_object_clause]

The best you can do is create a role and grant the role to Amy, but you will still have to grant privileges on each individual table to the role.

```
create role analyst;
grant analyst to amy;

grant read on hr.countries to analyst;
grant read on hr.departments to analyst;
grant read on hr.employees to analyst;
```

Comment: thanks reply , if I have 100 tables need to grant to Amy , I have repeatedly do grant read on table1 to analyst for 100 times ? if yes , is there any way can do it by one single script rather than do it 100 times ?

Comment: Yes, loop over user_all_tables and use `execute immediate` to grant read to a role. (I consider 'grant select' as deprecated because it gives permission to lock tables, which 'read' doesn’t.)

Answer (score 1):

To create a role and grant it to amy:

```
create role select_all_tables;
grant select_all_tables to amy;
alter user amy default role select_all_tables;
```

Use the following query to generate a script, which you can copy/paste and run to complete all the grants:

```
select 'grant select on '|| owner || '.' || table_name ||' to select_all_tables;' 
from dba_tables where owner='SCHEMA';
```

copy and paste the output, and execute it as as script.

```
grant select on schema.table1 to select_all_tables;
grant select on schema.table2 to select_all_tables;
...
```

If you would rather grant the privileges directly and not use a role, alter the script query:

```
select 'grant select on '|| owner || '.' || table_name ||' to amy;' 
from dba_tables where owner='SCHEMA';
```

and then run the output as a script:

```
grant select on schema.table1 to amy;
grant select on schema.table2 to amy;
...
```

Answer (score -2):

```
grant select on table to public;
```

But be careful when you do that -- make sure it's what you really want to do.

Comment: PUBLIC isn't exactly a "specific user" (which is what the OP wants). And it still grants privileges on a single table, so ... what is your point?